# Free monad and type constraints

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, constraints, typeclass

I am looking for practical strategies or tips for dealing with constraints in haskell, as illustrated by the case below.

---

I have a functor `Choice` and I want to transform an interpreter from `Choice x` functor to `m x` to an interpreter from `Free Choice x` to `m x`.

```
-- Choice : endofunctor  
data Choice next = Choice next next deriving (Show)
instance Functor Choice where 
   fmap f (Choice a b) = Choice (f a) (f b)

-- I have a function from the functor to a monad m
inter1 :: Choice x -> IO x
inter1 (Choice a b) = do 
  x <- readLn :: IO Bool 
  return $ if x then a else b

-- universal property gives me a function from the free monad to m 
go1 :: Free Choice x -> IO x
go1 = interpMonad inter1
```

where

```
type Free f a = FreeT f Identity a
data FreeF f r x = FreeF (f x) | Pure r deriving (Show)
newtype FreeT f m r = MkFreeT { runFreeT :: m (FreeF f r (FreeT f m r)) }

instance Show (m (FreeF f a (FreeT f m a))) => Show (FreeT f m a) where
  showsPrec d (MkFreeT m) = showParen (d > 10) $
    showString "FreeT " . showsPrec 11 m

instance (Functor f, Monad m) => Functor (FreeT f m) where
    fmap (f::a -> b) (x::FreeT f m a)  =
        MkFreeT $ liftM f'  (runFreeT x)
                where f' :: FreeF f a (FreeT f m a) -> FreeF f b (FreeT f m b)
                      f' (FreeF (fx::f (FreeT f m a))) =  FreeF $ fmap (fmap f) fx
                      f' (Pure r) = Pure $ f r

instance (Functor f, Monad m) => Applicative (FreeT f m) where
  pure a = MkFreeT . return $ Pure a
  (<*>) = ap

instance (Functor f, Monad m) => Monad (FreeT f m) where
    return = MkFreeT . return . Pure
    (MkFreeT m) >>= (f :: a -> FreeT f m b)  =  MkFreeT $ -- m (FreeF f b (FreeT f m b))
           m  >>= -- run the effect in the underlying monad !
             \case FreeF fx -> return . FreeF . fmap (>>= f) $ fx -- continue to run effects
                   Pure r -> runFreeT (f r) -- apply the transformation

interpMonad :: (Functor f, Functor m, Monad m) =>
               (forall x . f x -> m x) ->
               forall x. Free f x -> m x
interpMonad interp (MkFreeT iFfxF) = (\case
      Pure x -> return x
      FreeF fxF -> let mmx =  interp $ fmap (interpMonad interp) fxF
                   in join mmx) . runIdentity $ iFfxF
```

All is fine until I require `Show x` in my interpreter.

```
interp2 :: Show x => Choice x -> IO x
interp2 (Choice a b) = return a -- we follow left


go2 :: Show x => Free Choice x -> IO x
go2  = interpMonad interp2   -- FAILS
```

Then it can not find the show constraint to apply in interp2

I suspected the quantifiers were the problem, so I simplified to

```
lifting :: (forall x . x -> b) ->
           (forall x.  x -> b)
lifting = id

lifting2 :: (forall x . Show x => x -> b) ->
            (forall x . Show x => x -> b)
lifting2 = id


somefunction :: Show x => x -> String
somefunction = lifting show    -- FAILS

somefunction2 :: Show x => x -> String
somefunction2 = lifting2 show  -- OK
```

This highlight the problem : `Could not deduce (Show x1) arising from a use of ‘show’ from the context (Show x)` we have two distinct type variable, and constraint do not flow from one to the other.

---

I could write some specialized function playing with the constraints as follows (does not work btw) but my question is what are the practical strategies for dealing with this ? (the equivalent of undefined, look at the type, go on...)

```
interpMonad2 :: (Functor f, Functor m, Monad m) =>
               (forall x . ( Show (f x)) => f x -> m x) ->
               forall x.  ( Show (Free f x)) => Free f x -> m x
interpMonad2 interp (MkFreeT iFfxF) = (\case
      Pure x -> return x
      FreeF fxF -> let mmx =  interp $ fmap (interpMonad interp) fxF
                   in join mmx) . runIdentity $ iFfxF
```

---

edit

based on the answer provided, here is the modification for the  `lifting`  function.

```
lifting :: forall b c. Proxy c
           ->  (forall x . c x => x -> b)
           ->  (forall x . c x => x -> b)
lifting _ = id


somefunction3 :: Show x => x -> String
somefunction3 = lifting (Proxy :: Proxy Show) show
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see your interpMonad function, so I will include one possible definition here:

```
interpMonad :: forall f m x . (Functor f, Monad m) 
            => (forall y . f y -> m y) -> Free f x -> m x 
interpMonad xx = go . runIdentity . runFreeT  where 
  go (FreeF x) = xx x >>= go . runIdentity . runFreeT
  go (Pure  x) = return x
```

In order to also have a class constraint on the inner function, you simply add the constraint to the inner function. You also need the correct constraint on the type `Free`, and you need the extra `Proxy` to help the typechecker out a bit. Otherwise, the definition of the function is identical:

```
interpMonadC :: forall f m x c . (Functor f, Monad m, c (Free f x)) 
             => Proxy c 
             -> (forall y . c y => f y -> m y) 
             -> (Free f x -> m x) 
interpMonadC _ xx = go . runIdentity . runFreeT  where 
  go (FreeF x) = xx x >>= go . runIdentity . runFreeT
  go (Pure  x) = return x
```

And now quite simply:

```
>:t interpMonadC (Proxy :: Proxy Show) interp2
interpMonadC (Proxy :: Proxy Show) interp2
  :: Show x => Free Choice x -> IO x
```

Comment: So by using proxy at call site, we pass a value which we choose to be of type `Proxy Show`, so that `c` type variable is `Show`, type which is used as a constrain with (via *ConstraintKinds* options) . that **same** constraint is used in the result function and in the inner function which leads the compiler to look for a show instance on interp2, which it readily finds in its context.... I can understand those things but wonder how easily I will be able to write them

Comment: Isn't `interpMonad` a `retract`?

Comment: @arrowd : I forgot what retract was. but interMonad takes, AFAIK, a natural transformation interp2 (defined for all type x uniformly, obvious that going from `Choice a` to `Choice b` then transporting to `IO b` give the same function than transporting from `Choice a` to `IO a` then going to `IO b`) to another natural transformation. interp2 is an arrow in the category of endofunctor from `Choice` to `m` *viewed as a functor* and the free/forgetful adjunction give you, by initially, a unique arrow interpMonad from the monad `Free Choice` to `m` viewed as a monad

Comment: @arrowd so it's one direction of the isomorphism Endo(F, U(m)) / Endo (Free F, m)  . for functor categories Endo http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/endofunctor  . correction : 'a unique arrow interpMonad' => 'a unique arrow `interpMonad interp2`' above

Comment: I wonder what is the interpretation of constraints, categorically. `forall x`  is nice, but the real power comes from giving our computations some abilities

Comment: @nicolas I have always seen constraints as subsets. That is `forall (x : X) . C x => Proxy x` denotes the subset of `X` which satisfies the predicate `C`.